# how to update sqlite database with only one field to change

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Java language and the android studio.
Recently I tried to create the App with User Activity(Login,Register)

and now I am trying to create the Change Password activity, and  I am really confused about how to update my sqldb

I have three table : ID, username, password

```
public void updatePassword(String password) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
     db.update(TABLE_USERS, values + " = " , null );
     db.close();
}
```

and I always get error in db.update

thanks before for everyone. have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess in the table there is at least another column like `username` and maybe another like `id`.
You want to change the password of an existing user, so you must have either the `id` or the `username` of that user to do so.
Say that you have the `username`.
Change your method to this:

```
public boolean updatePassword(String username, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
    int rows = db.update(TABLE_USERS, values,  "username = ?" , new String[] {username} );
    db.close();
    return (rows > 0);
}
```

The placeholder `?` will be replaced by the value of the variable `username` when you call the method and so only the row with that `username` will be updated.
 
You call the method like this:

```
boolean updateSuccessful = updatePassword("johndoe2019", "123456");
```

If the value of the variable `updateSuccessful` is `true` this means that the password of the user with username `"johndoe2019"` changed to `"123456"`.